# Creating a secondary site-packages directory (and loading packages from .pth files therein)

Tags: python, pythonpath

I would like to install some packages into a third-party `site-packages` directory (beyond the standard system locations). Is there any way to set this up such that .pth files therein are respected?

---

Background: I'm using OS X, virtualenv, and homebrew. There are a few packages (notably wxPython in my case) that do not install nicely through pip into virtualenv. In these cases, there are homebrew packages that work in their stead.  Homebrew creates a third site-packages folder in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. I'd like to simply point to this folder and leave the maintenance of all items there under `brew`'s control.  It seems, however, that this is not possible.

- Appending to the path via `$PYTHONPATH` does not load .pth files. ([Should Python 2.6 on OS X deal with multiple easy-install.pth files in $PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794107/should-python-2-6-on-os-x-deal-with-multiple-easy-install-pth-files-in-pythonpa))
- Python does not allow nesting or recursive use of .pth files. ([Nested .pth Files or Loading Extra site-dirs from a Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600938/nested-pth-files-or-loading-extra-site-dirs-from-a-network))
- The wrapper for virtualenv `add2virtualenv` adds some extra smarts to the .pth file beyond simply having the directory listed, but I believe it simply reorders the path list.

I'm certainly not the only one interested in this issue. I'd wager a good number of the generic 'pth files not working' questions and posts online that I've stumbled across are related to this issue. Is there a good solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at the [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) module.  It provides the function [`addsitedir`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.addsitedir) which should do what you want.

The easiest way to use this would be to create a file named `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` and place it in a current `PYTHONPATH` directory (or any directory that ends up on `sys.path`) with the following contents:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/python2.7')
```

When Python is starting an attempt is made to import `sitecustomize` and then `usercustomize`, which is why this works.  From the site documentation:

> After these path manipulations, an attempt is made to import a module named `sitecustomize`, which can perform arbitrary site-specific customizations. It is typically created by a system administrator in the site-packages directory. If this import fails with an `ImportError` exception, it is silently ignored.
>
> After this, an attempt is made to import a module named `usercustomize`, which can perform arbitrary user-specific customizations, if `ENABLE_USER_SITE` is true. This file is intended to be created in the user site-packages directory (see below), which is part of `sys.path` unless disabled by `-s`. An `ImportError` will be silently ignored.

Comment: Do sitecustomize.py or usercustomize.py automatically get run on startup? Edit: [yes, yes they do](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html). Thanks!

Comment: @MattB. Yes, edited my answer with some additional info.  The documentation comes from the top of the site module page that I linked in my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand fully how work site, but: (1) shouldn't it by addsitedir('/usr/local'), i.e. the alternative prefix (but it does not work for me), or (2) addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages') the path to append, and in that second case, why not just adding it to the PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: Answer to myself: the difference of using site.addsitedir is that the .pth file are "executed". However a colleague of mine is telling me that this feature is not necessary anymore. Would anyone disagree ?

Comment: Yes - if you are using egg files or a particular path structure.

Comment: Hint: use `usercustomize`. On some linux distros a global sitecustomize exists, on some not. This can lead to confusing behaviour. No linux distro provides a usercustomize.

Comment: @guettli: usercustomize seems disabled in venvs. Any idea what to do then?

Answer (score 1):

There was [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) specifically addressing the creation of per-user `site-packages` directories, to deal with the situation where the user has no admin access to the system-wide `site-packages`.

For example on Unix (including Mac OS), and assuming one is using Python 3.6, one can create the following directory and place `.pth` files inside there

`~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`