# setting python search path in config file without environment variables (i.e. PYTHONPATH)

Tags: python, unix, pythonpath

Is there some way to set python's search path in a config file *without* setting `PYTHONPATH`, i.e. some default configuration file that python reads when it starts?

Comment: Related: [Creating a secondary site-packages directory (and loading packages from .pth files therein)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10693706/95735)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- List additional paths in a [`.pth` file in one of the standard locations](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) (usually your `site-packages` location). See [How to add a Python import path using a .pth file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700375/how-to-add-a-python-import-path-using-a-pth-file) as well.
- Add additional paths to `sys.path` in `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` modules (detailed in the [`site` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html)). Your `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` could look something like:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path[0:0] = [
      '/foo/bar',
      '/spam/eggs',
  ]
  ```

  where the two extra entries would be inserted into `sys.path` at the front.

  You can also call `site.addsitedir` with a path in such a module, which will add that path to `sys.path` *and* process any `.pth` files found there.

Comment: so assuming that I don't have (or can't rely on) root access, I would put `sitecustomize.py` in the path pointed to by [`site.USER_SITE`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE)?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid messing with Python's system installation you could list the paths in `.pth` files that are in your [`USER_SITE`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) directory e.g., `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. You could also put `usercustomize.py` there and call arbitrary code such as `sys.path.insert(0, path)`, `site.addsitedir(path)`.