# Using Python .pth files assuming no access to site-packages directory

Tags: python, path, package, sys.path

In my current system, all directories such as `.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` are under global admin control and are standardized across users.

However, I would like to add a collection of my own directories to be brought into the PYTHONPATH on startup, preferably in an easy-to-manage way like [using a `.pth` file within a secondary site directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693706/creating-a-secondary-site-packages-directory-and-loading-packages-from-pth-fil)

Is there a way I can achieve this through normal Python channels, but *without* needing to make any kind of change to the standard locations where Python looks for path elements?

I'm specifically wondering if there is a way to just place a file like `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` *anywhere* in a folder that is in the PYTHONPATH and expect that they will be automatically executed? (Rather than getting this behavior by placing such files within an admin directory like `site-packages`, which is what I want to avoid.)

My goal is to place a text file, `paths.pth` in some directory, like `/home/my_configs/python_stuff/` and then *just* need to place *that directory only* in the PYTHONPATH via, e.g. a `.bashrc` file. Then, at least, I only manually maintain one path to be added, and it's easier to version control or parameterize what gets loaded by changing what is in that `.pth` file.

If the admin limitations weren't in place, I could trivially do this in `site-packages` but I need a solution that works totally outside of that.

In `/.bashrc` I have this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ems/python_paths/:$PYTHONPATH
```

In the directory `/home/ems/python_paths/` I have just two files, `sitecustomize.py` and `paths.pth` (but I've also tried adding an `__init__.py` there too, which (as expected) didn't help). These two files look like this:

**sitecustomize.py**

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/home/ems/python_paths/")
```

**paths.pth**

```
/home/ems/ws/Research/Projects/python-util/src/util/
/home/ems/ws/Research/Projects/python-efficacy/src/efficacy/
```

The contents of `paths.pth` are just exactly what used to be directly exported in `.bashrc` and, for instance, permits me to do `from util.DataManager import DataManager` as a top-level import.

But after setting up the various files above, commenting out `exports` to `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc`, and getting a fresh terminal, I see this:

```
ems@computer ~ $ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
Hello
>>> from util.DataManager import DataManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named util.DataManager
```

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to already says how to do this.  You need to put the `sitecustomize.py` in the directory on the Python path, and have it use `addsitedit` to add `/some/other/dir` as a site dir, and then `.pth` files in `/some/other/dir` will work.  You could also use the [user-specific packages directory](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/).

Comment: No, this does not work. If you read the `site` docs, the file `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` seems to be required to appear in `site-packages` *not in* the "other" folders that are on the path. It won't auto-execute them unless it finds them in one of the special places, and I'm asking how to get around that.

Comment: Yes, it does.  As that answer and the docs say, Python just does `import sitecustomize`, which will work as long as your `sitecustomize` is anywhere on the Python path.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have `/home/ely/configs/python_path/` exported to `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc`, I have an `__init__.py` file in there, as well as `sitecustomize.py` (also tried `usercustomize.py`), which contain the relevant code to add my `.pth` file. If I source the `.bashrc` after doing this, the `sitecustomize.py` file *does not* get executed on startup.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of your `sitecustomize.py` and the contents of `sys.path`.  Also, why do you have `__init__.py`?  You don't want that if you want to import `sitecustomize.py` directly (which is what `site` will do), and that could be confusing it.

Comment: I tried the `__init__.py` thing just because it was not working without it, but adding it did not help. Will edit with details.

Comment: Is the `utils` directory a package?  That is, does `utils` contain an `__init__.py`?  If it does, you should have its parent directory (i.e., `/home/ems/ws/Research/Projects/python-util/src/`) in the .PTH file.

Comment: Again, these *exact* paths worked fine when manually exported through .bashrc. Those paths and the respective `__init__.py` files are not the problem. These were all among the first things I tried, but thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: It's hard to debug these kinds of problems over the internet because there are so many fiddly little details that can make it not work.  I have essentially the same setup you describe and it works perfectly.

Comment: Very true. I will keep working on it and update the post if I discover what setting is different for me that is preventing it.

Comment: @EMS Is this still relevant? I might have some answers.

Answer (score 1):

There was [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) specifically addressing the creation of per-user `site-packages` directories, to deal with the situation where the user has no admin access to the system-wide `site-packages`.

For example on Unix (including Mac OS), and assuming one is using Python 3.6, one can create the following directory and place `.pth` files inside there

`~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`